# WPF Comparing values from different buttons

Tags: c#, wpf, button, compare

Let's say that I'd like to make an app that has got 3 buttons, one button makes some math (and the result is X), another one makes some math (and the result is Y), and the last button says "Compare", and compares X and Y.

How is it possible to make? I haven't really rogrammed outside of console applications.

What if the value I want to pass is the name of dictionary? Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Event handler for third button inside that you can write the logic to compare the the values.

EG-: if you are storing your result in text-box you can compare the Results inside the text box by using `Textbox.Text` Property

[Compare Two Textbox Values in WPF](http://zapone.org/barton/2015/01/21/compare-two-textbox-values-and-show-error-in-wpf/)